# A Obfuscated JS, manual replacement too much trouble, is there any tool or method

Tags: javascript

It's Obfuscated way below this way

```
   var a = document.getElementById('a');
    a.innerHTML = 'hello world';
```

break all literal passed to the anonymous function

```
!function(a, b, c, d, e, f){
    a[d] = a[b][c](d);
    a[d][e]=f;}(this, 'document', 'getElementById', 'a', 'innerHTML', 'hello world');
```

[obfuscated JS file](https://passport.baidu.com/static/passpc-base/dv/e.min.js)

Comment: A simple search-and-replace should do.

Comment: @Bergi ,I only understand it, in fact it is far more difficult than the example I gave, I give up to replace it to restore it, which is difficult, but also more than one file. I have extracted through the breakpoint I want the function , But I still want to know how to quickly restore it